# Typescript: Type an array to include every key of an enum

Tags: typescript

I would like to know if it is possible to have an array of object contain all keys from a certain enumeration.

An example:

```js
enum Permission {
  CAN_LIST_POST = 'list:post';
  CAN_DELETE_POST = 'delete:post';
}

interface RoleOption {
  title: string;
  value: Permission;
  explanation: string
}

export const RoleOptions = (): RoleOption[] => [
  { title: "List post", value: Permission.CAN_LIST_POST, explanation: "A user can list the posts" },
  // An error should be thrown here because we don't have Permission.CAN_DELETE_POST
]
```

I have tried using `keyof`

```js
interface RoleOption {
  title: string;
  value: keyof Permission;
  explanation: string
}
```

and many others but no lucky. My main idea behind of this is that whenever we have a new permission in the system we only have to add to `Permission` interface and we will get errors around the system telling where we should add handling of this new permission

Comment: Maybe you should use an object with the same keys instead of an array.